# Prevent Processes from Calling Eachother

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I am trying to keep some fields on 2 records in sync *without* using Apex... A simplified object model is as follows:

```
ObjectA.TextField
ObjectA.LinkToObjectB

ObjectB.TextField
ObjectB.LinkToObjectA
```

Using Process Builder + Visual Workflow, I am able to create a new instance of `ObjectB` whenever an instance of `ObjectA` is created with the value of `TextField` populated.  There bi-directional linking that is established as well.  This allows me to keep the value of `TextField` on `ObjectB` up to date whenever `ObjectA` is updated.

Now, I would like to set things up such that whenever `ObjectB` is updated, the value in `TextField` copied to `ObjectA`.  If I do this, then my first process will be fired and updated `ObjectB` again... Ideally, I would like to prevent these processes from invoking eachother.

It is not really an option to a condition that compares `ObjectA.TextField` to `ObjectB.TextField` since there could be dozens of fields to keep in sync.

Yes, I realize that the data is very much denormalized, but changing this is not an option as this point.

I considered using timestamping to do achieve this, but am not exactly sure how this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution which seems to work pretty well as follows...

Add a `Checkbox` field to each object called `SyncIndicator` with a default value of 0.  Now the object model looks as follows:

```
ObjectA.TextField
ObjectA.LinkToObjectB
ObjectA.SyncIndicator

ObjectB.TextField
ObjectB.LinkToObjectA
ObjectB.SyncIndicator
```

The way that I have things setup, Process Builder is used because it can be triggered when an object is inserted/updated.  The more complex task of inserting/updating a related entity is handled by Flows.  So, the main thing that Process Builder does is trigger a Flow.

I changed my Flow such that when a related object is created, it sets the `SyncIndicator` field to 1 and when a related object is updated, it toggles the `SyncIndicator` to the opposite value.

This allows me to detect whether or not a Process was caused by a Flow using the following formula:

```
IF(
  ISNEW(),
  NOT([ObjectA__c].SyncIndicator__c),
  PRIORVALUE([ObjectA__c].SyncIndicator__c) = [ObjectA__c].SyncIndicator__c
)
```

Basically, if `SyncIndicator` is set to 1 for an insert, or its value has changed for an update, then I can safely ignore.

For good measure, the following Process Builder option is *deselected* as well:

> Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are
>   made to the record?